# Can I force cleanup of old tombstones?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, tombstone

I have recently lowered `gc_grace_seconds` for a CQL table. I am running `LeveledCompactionStrategy`. Is it possible for me to force purging of old tombstones from my SSTables?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Your tombstones will disappear on their own through compaction bit make sure you are running repair or they may come back from the dead.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_about_deletes_c.html

#### Adding some more details:

Tombstones are not immediately available for deletion until both:

1) gc_grace_seconds has expired

2) they meet the requirements configured in tombstone compaction sub-properties

#### I need to free up disk by expiring tombstones, how do I do this quickly?

1) Run a repair to ensure your tombstones are consistent

2) Decrease gc_grace_seconds for your table ([alter table statement](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/tabProp.html))

3) Configure your [compaction sub properties](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/compactSubprop.html) to speed up tombstone removal:

Decrease tombstone_compaction_interval and decrease tombstone_threshold, or set unchecked_tombstone_compaction to true to ignore both conditions and collect based purely on gc grace.

#### Is it working?

You can see statistics about tombstones in `nodetool cfstats` and by using the sstable metatdata utility found in your tools directory `sstablemetadata <sstable filenames>`.

Comment: Nodetool garbagecollect can be useful in modern versions.

Comment: "The `nodetool garbagecollect` command is available from Cassandra 3.10 onwards. This command runs a series of smaller compactions that also check overlapping sstables. It is more CPU intensive and time-consuming than nodetool compact, but requires less free disk space."   
https://www.instaclustr.com/support/documentation/cassandra/using-cassandra/managing-tombstones-in-cassandra/